# compare only hours in timestamp column postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table with date like that:

```
OBJECT    TIMESTAMP_START        TIMESTAMP_END
House     2020-02-20 09:33:24    2020-02-20 09:33:33
Dog       2020-02-20 18:00:03    2020-02-21 18:33:22
Cat       2020-02-11 19:00:00    2020-02-11 19:15:23
```

I need to extract all objects,start timestamp and end timestamp  whose timestamp start is between (18:00 hours and 09:00)

In that case was Dog and Cat

How could I make that in postgreSql ? Do you think is possible easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean between 18:00 and 09:00 the **next day**? Or simply between 09:00 and 18:00?

Comment: Well, I've explained very bad, sorry for my english. Start_time > 18:00 and Start_time < 09.00. All objects that are executed between 1800 and 0900

Comment: Just cast the timestamp to time `(TIMESTAMP '2020-02-20 09:33:24')::time `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with TIME alone because in hours 09:00 is always less than 18:00, and from 09:00 to 18:00 is the time to be excluded.  You can get this by truncating to the start and adding the appropriate interval.

```
with the_table (object, timestamp_start,timestamp_end ) as 
   ( values ('House', '2020-02-20 09:33:24'::timestamp, '2020-02-20 09:33:33'::timestamp)  
          , ('Dog',   '2020-02-20 18:00:03'::timestamp, '2020-02-21 18:33:22'::timestamp)  
          , ('Cat',   '2020-02-11 19:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-02-11 19:15:23'::timestamp)
          , ('Mouse', '2020-02-11 20:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-02-12 08:00:00'::timestamp)    
   )
select *
from the_table
where timestamp_start between  
      date_trunc('day', timestamp_start) + interval '18 hours' and 
      date_trunc('day', timestamp_start) + interval '1 day 9 hours' ;
```

Of course this get all such rows matching the times even if they are years old. You might want to consider that as well. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the timestamp to `time`

```
select *
from the_table
where timestamp_start::time > time '18:00'
  and timestamp_start::time < time '09:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you exclude both bounds, a rare case where [`BETWEEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) is correct:

```
select *
from   tbl
where  timestamp_start::time NOT BETWEEN time '09:00' AND time '18:00';
```